# Cannot Update Mac - Update Won't Show

Tags: software-update

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports), currently running MacOS 11.0.1. I want to update to 11.4, but the update simply won't show in settings, it just says 'Your Mac is up to date'. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: Is it a company computer? IT can manage which updates are allowed/shown.

Comment: @JBallin No, it is a personal computer.